# exclude elements from hash based on array

Tags: ruby

I have an array of hashes

```
x = [{:name=>'a', :value=1}, {:name=>'b', :value=2}, {:name=>'c', :value=3}]
```

and string array

```
y = ["a", "c"]
```

how could I exclude elements from `x` based on `y` ? so that at the end I have `x = [ {:name=>'b', :value=2} ]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Enumerable#reject](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-reject)

```
x.reject {|h| y.include? h[:name]}
# => [{:name=>"b", :value=>2}]
```

Note: If you want to modify the original object, you can use `reject!` instead.

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer provided by @Santhosh is absolutely correct, on huge arrays it is not efficient due to lookup in `y` on each iteration. That might be faster:

```
xgr = x.group_by { |e| e[:name] }
x - y.map { |e| xgr[e] }.flatten
#⇒ [ {:name=>'b', :value=2} ]
```